# Postgresql Error Generation Expression Is Not Immutable When Referencing Timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I am receiving an error when I try to create a generated tsvector column that has a timestamp included.  The error is

`ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable

SQL state: 42P17`

Here is the generated column I am trying to get to work.  I have tried removing the format, but that didn't seem to help.

`CREATE TABLE lms.test_person ( first_name text, last_name text, date_of_birth timestamp without time zone, search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (to_tsvector('english', first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' || TO_CHAR(date_of_birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD') )) STORED );`

I have also tried

`CREATE TABLE lms.test_person ( first_name text, last_name text, date_of_birth timestamp without time zone, search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (to_tsvector('english', first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' ||  date_of_birth::text )) STORED );`

because I read that the concatenation of a non-text item is not immutable, but that did not seem to work either.
If I drop the date_of_birth from the to_tsvector everything works fine.  I am using version 15.1

Comment: `TO_CHAR` is not immutable because it depends on the timezone settings and current time - at least for some format strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can go around this by creating your own immutable wrapper function and use it ,

```
CREATE FUNCTION immutable_to_char(timestamp without time zone) RETURNS text AS
$$ select TO_CHAR($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); $$
LANGUAGE sql immutable;
```

and then do your query as ,

```
CREATE TABLE lms.test_person ( 
    first_name text, 
    last_name text, 
    date_of_birth timestamp without time zone, 
    search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS  (
        to_tsvector('english', 
                    first_name || ' ' || 
                    last_name  || ' ' || 
                    immutable_to_char(date_of_birth) 
                   )
    ) STORED 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did get a working solution.  It was a matter of cobbling together the right immutable functions to get it to work.  I used date_part to extract the parts I needed and formatted it manually.  Note: I went with a different format than I originally posted above, but the solution can be adjusted to use the above format.  I had also used the suggestion of examining the functions for immutability from a psql prompt using \df+

```
\df+ to_tsvector
```

Here is what I came up with in the end.

```
CREATE TABLE lms.test_person (
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    date_of_birth timestamp without time zone,
    search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (to_tsvector('english', first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' || lpad(date_part('month', date_of_birth)::text, 2, '0') || lpad(date_part('day', date_of_birth)::text, 2, '0') || lpad(date_part('year', date_of_birth)::text, 4, '0') )) STORED
);
```